# Avoiding code duplication for template instantiations depending on runtime parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working with a C++ library written by someone else which (unfortunately imo) implements several algorithms encapsulated in classes whose behaviour can be fine tuned via parameters that are passed as template parameters (the parameters are generally also classes). So for example there might be a class template like this:

```
template<typename Param1, typename Param2, typename Param3>
class Foo {
  // ...
};
```

I want to write a program using this library that will need to create instances of `Foo` based on runtime information. My problem is that assuming that there are `N1`, `N2` and `N3` valid types that can be passed for `Param1`, `Param2` and `Param3`, I might need to create up to `N1 x N2 x N3` branches at some point in my code when I want to instantiate different spezializations of `Foo`. Say for example that I at runtime I am given three strings via user input and each of those decides which type one of the template parameters of `Foo` should be, then I would need to do something like this:

```
std::string s1, s2, s3;

// instantiate s1, s2, s3 from user input

if (s1 == "Param1_1" && s2 == "Param2_1" && s3 == "Param3_1") {
  Foo<Param1_1, Param2_1, Param3_1> foo;
} else if (s1 == "Param1_1" && s2 == "Param2_1" && s3 == "Param3_2") {
  Foo<Param1_1, Param2_1, Param3_2> foo;
}

// ...
```

Where `Param1_1` is a valid type for `Param1` and so on. How can I implement this more elegantly? (ideally only using C++11 or at most C++17 features).

Comment: More elegantly? I don't see a way how to get around writing all those combinations manually, at best shortening the code written by use of some macros, but if *that* is more 'elegant' is questionable. A bit *faster* than this possibly long if/else chain might be hashing, though: `std::unordered_map<std::string, void(*)(/* parameters as needed */)`, which you might fill with some lambdas, like `map["Param1_1\x1FParam2_1\x1FParam3_1"] = [](/*...*/) { Foo<Param1_1, Param2_1, Param3_1> foo; /* ...  */ };`.

Comment: Side note: 0x1f is the ASCII unit separator character, chose another one, if you prefer, but that one is hard for the user to enter on the keyboard...

Comment: [jit proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1609r0.html) might interest you. even if you still have to do the dispatch.

Comment: I would opt for something simple. Just put everything after the `if` into a generic lambda and then call it with `foo`. Like `auto continuation = [&, this](auto foo) { ... }; if(...) { continuation(Foo<Param1_1, Param2_1, Param3_1>()); } else if(...) { continuation(Foo<...>()); } ...`. For C++11, get rid of the lambda and put this into a template (member) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::variant` (c++17) for each type and use `std::visit` for the dispatch:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct Tag{ using type = T;};

std::variant<Tag<T1>, Tag<T2>, Tag<T3>/*..*/> getType(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s == "Param1") { return Tag<T1>{}; }
    else if (s == "Param2") { return Tag<T2>{}; }
    // ...
}

void bar(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3)
{
    auto v1 = getType(s1);
    auto v2 = getType(s2);
    auto v3 = getType(s3);

    std::visit([](auto t1, auto t2, auto t3)
              {
                  Foo<typename decltype(t1)::type,
                      typename decltype(t2)::type,
                      typename decltype(t3)::type> foo;
                  /*..*/
               }, v1, v2, v3);
}
```

Comment: Interesting... [*'Effectively returns `std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(vis), std::get<is>(std::forward<Variants>(vars))...)`, where `is...` is `vars.index()...`.'*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) Question: How is it possible that we get compile time constants this way? `vars.index()` itself isn't.

Comment: @Aconcagua it instantiates the visitor for each index because it conditionally calls them all, but only actually calls it for one. So at compile time the compiler still sees all branches and the visitor must be compatible for all 27 combinations.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Ah, thanks. So in the end (internally) not really different from original approach in question, but now based on indices instead of strings – just hidden away from us...

Comment: This looks very interesting, I will try this out and accept if it works out (although I'm not doubting the correctness of your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C++11, you could create a sequence of functions, one for every type, to select and transmit the correct template parameter; the last function called (the first one, in the following example) could create the `Foo` object.

Not really elegant but you can avoid the `N1 x N2 x N3` multiplication effect.

```
template <typename ... PrevParams>
void for_s3 (std::string const & s3)
 {
   if ( "Param3_1" == s3 )
      Foo<PrevParams..., Param3_1>{}
   else if ( "Param3_2" == s3 )
      Foo<PrevParams..., Param3_2>{};
   // other cases 
 }    

template <typename ... PrevParams>
void for_s2 (std::string const & s2, std::string const & s3)
 {
   if ( "Param2_1" == s2 )
      for_s3<PrevParams..., Param2_1>(s3);
   else if ( "Param2_2" == s2 )
      for_s3<PrevParams..., Param2_2>(s3);
   // other cases 
 }    

void for_s1 (std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2, std::string const & s3)
 {
   if ( "Param1_1" == s1 )
      for_s2<Param1_1>(s2, s3);
   else if ( "Param1_2" == s1 )
      for_s2<Param1_2>(s2, s3);
   // other cases 
 }
```

Maybe a little more elegant and flexible (you can easily add other string and parameters), but with a greater run-time cost, a two-function solution

```
template <typename ... Params>
void select_foo ()
 {
   Foo<Params...>  f;

   // do something with f
 }

template <typename ... PrevParams, typename ... Ts>
void select_foo (std::string const & s, Ts const & ... ts)
 {
   if ( "Param1_1" == s )
       select_foo<PrevParams..., Param1_1>(ts...);
   else ( "Param1_2" == s )
       select_foo<PrevParams..., Param1_2>(ts...);
   // other Param1_x cases
   else if ( "Param2_1" == s )
       select_foo<PrevParams..., Param2_1>(ts...);
   else ( "Param2_2" == s )
       select_foo<PrevParams..., Param2_2>(ts...);
   // other Param2_x cases
   else if ( "Param3_1" == s )
       select_foo<PrevParams..., Param3_1>(ts...);
   else ( "Param3_1" == s )
       select_foo<PrevParams..., Param3_2>(ts...);
   // other Param3_x cases
 }
```